# In how many ways can you choose theee numbers from 1 to 100 with different sum?

Tags: combinations

In the name of Allah
In how many ways can you choose three numbers from 1 to 100 with different sum, If you can choose a number more than one time?
Eg: {3,2,1} is same as {1,1,4} because 1+1+4=3+2+1.
I know how to calculate how many ways is there to choose three numbers if you can choose a number more than one time by counting the answers of the equation:
x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>+ x<sub>4</sub> +...x<sub>100</sub> = 3 (If x<sub>i</sub> is a whole number.)
But I have no idea about this one.

Comment: You can obtain all sums from $3$ to $300$.

Comment: It is highly unusual to consider $\{3,2,1\}$ the same as $\{1,1,4\}$... but if that is really what you want... you are asking how many terms would be in the expansion of $(x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^{100})^3$ after simplification.  It should be clear that every result from $3$ on up to $300$ is possible.

Comment: If you need further convincing... consider the sequence of outcomes:  $(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,1,3),(1,1,4),\dots,(1,1,99),(1,1,100),(1,2,100),(1,3,100),(1,4,100),\dots,(1,99,100),(1,100,100),(2,100,100),\dots,(99,100,100),(100,100,100)$ where to get the next term in the sequence we increase the last appearing element by $1$ which is able to be increased.  We get a resulting sum which is exactly $1$ more than the previous sum, and this is always able to be done up until all of the numbers are $100$ at which point we can no longer continue.